# new discrete variable with three levels (good, okay, bad)

Tags: r

R has a built-in dataset called attitude. 
Create a new discrete variable complain.level with three levels, `bad`, `okay` and `good`.

ATTEMPT 1:

```
complain.level=revalue(attitude$complaints,c("bad"=(0:60),"okay"=(61:80), "good"=(81:100)))
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
library(dplyr)
attitude%>%mutate(complaints.level = if_else(complaints<61,"bad",
                                             if_else(complaints>80,"good",
                                                     "okay")))
```

As suggested by Simon, we can also use `case_when`

```
attitude%>%mutate(complaints.level = case_when(complaints<61 ~ "bad",
                                               complaints>80 ~ "good",
                                               TRUE~"okay"))
```

Comment: You should use `case_when` instead of nested `if_else`.

Comment: Is there a way without using the package "dplyr"?

Comment: 'data=data.frame(complain.level, attitude$complaints)'
'avg.cl<- tapply(data$attitude.complaints, data$complain.level, mean)'
'avg.cl'